# Alternative to SQL Union

Tags: sql-server, union

I have a list of numbers. I want to determine what table they are in from a list of three tables and return the table name and the number in a single result set.

```
Nums: 1,2,3,4,8,9
Tables: tb1, tb2, tb3
```

Normally, I'd query each table and `Union` them all together, but I want to know if there's a way to have the statements make the list smaller as it goes to hopefully improve efficiency over a large amount of data. Here's an example of what I want to do:

```
Checking tb1 first, I find that 1,2,3 are present.
Then check tb2 for the remaining numbers (4,8,9).
If none of the numbers are found, then check tb3, otherwise the query should end.
```

Here's two possible returns:

```
TableName | Num        *|*       TableName | Num
----------------       *|*       ----------------
tb1       | 1          *|*       tb1       | 1
tb1       | 2          *|*       tb1       | 2
tb1       | 3          *|*       tb1       | 3
tb3       | 4          *|*       tb2       | 4
tb3       | 8          *|*       tb3       | 9
tb3       | 9          *|*       *** 8 wasn't found
```

Is there a way to do this, or is a `Union` still the best way?

Comment: You'll have to test it with your data, but I'd suspect UNION would still be preferable.

Comment: What does the query and the tables look like? The query optimizer will probably simplify the query and use the correct indexes, if any are available. Trying to second-guess it will typically result in *slower* queries.

Comment: For example, if there's a column constraint that prevents eg `1 `from appearing in tbl2, the optimizer won't search tbl2 for `1`.

Comment: When you have your column (with the numbers) indexed I strongly believe a `UNION` statement is the best approach and also very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun I scripted up two queries, one using the `UNION` method, and one attempting to use the logic you defined above, i.e. check table1, then look for the remaining items in table2, then table3, etc.

This was my script:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY);
DECLARE @table2 TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY);
DECLARE @table3 TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO @table1 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 9;
INSERT INTO @table2 SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4;
INSERT INTO @table3 SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 8;
SELECT id, 'table1' AS found FROM @table1 WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
UNION
SELECT id, 'table2' AS found FROM @table2 WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
UNION
SELECT id, 'table3' AS found FROM @table3 WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
ORDER BY id;

DECLARE @search TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO @search SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9;
WITH 
    nt1 AS (SELECT * FROM @search s EXCEPT SELECT * FROM @table1),
    nt2 AS (SELECT * FROM nt1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM @table2)
SELECT s.id, 'table1' AS found FROM (SELECT * FROM @search INTERSECT SELECT * FROM @table1) s
UNION ALL
SELECT s.id, 'table2' AS found FROM (SELECT * FROM nt1 INTERSECT SELECT * FROM @table2) s
UNION ALL
SELECT s.id, 'table3' AS found FROM (SELECT * FROM nt2 INTERSECT SELECT * FROM @table3) s
ORDER BY id;
```

I get the same results for each method, noting that this doesn't tell you non-matches, so probably isn't ideal?

I then viewed the whole script as an execution plan.  This isn't rocket science, and there's a pretty strong argument that introducing a new `@search` table is "cheating", also that using table variables to hold the data is wrong (should use physical tables even if they are temporary), and that the amount of data in my tables is far too small, etc.

However, in this flawed experiment I found the `UNION` method was more than twice as fast.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to experiment. I will stick to the `union` as everyone has suggested. I'm not familiar with `@search` tables, so maybe I'll have a look at those too. Thanks

Comment: `@search` is a table variable, they came in a while back, and are basically a mechanism to store small amounts of data without needing a physical table. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017